# Form Validation Error?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to run and validate a form but having some problem. Instead of displaying the form it displays the HttpResponse I put to display when form is not valid.

Here is my Model:

```
class Preference(models.Model):
CLASS_CHOICES = [('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3')]
BOARD_CHOICES = [('C', 'CBSE'), ('I', 'ICSE'), ('S', 'State Board')]
SLOT_CHOICES = [('M', 'Morning'), ('A', 'AfterNoon'), ('E', 'Evening')]
SUBJECT_CHOICES = [('H', 'HINDI'), ('M', 'MATH'), ('E', 'ENGLISH')]
LOCATION_CHOICES = [('M', 'My Home'), ('T', 'I am willing to travel')]
GENDER_CHOICES = [('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'), ('B', 'Both are Fine')]
Class = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=CLASS_CHOICES, default='1', blank=False)
Board = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BOARD_CHOICES, default='C', blank=False)
Subject = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SUBJECT_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
Frequency = models.IntegerField(default=7)
Slot = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=SLOT_CHOICES, default='E', blank=False)
Location = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=LOCATION_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
Gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M', blank=False)
Address = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
Travel = models.IntegerField(default=5)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
Contact = models.IntegerField(default=100)
```

Here is my form:

```
class PreferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Preference
    fields = ['Class', 'Board', 'Subject', 'Frequency', 'Slot', 'Location', 'Gender', 'Address',
              'Travel', 'Name', 'Contact']
    widgets = {
           'Board': forms.RadioSelect(),
           'Subject': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
           'Slot': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
           'Location': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
           'Gender': forms.RadioSelect()  }
```

And here is my view:

```
def pref2(request):
form = PreferenceForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    prefer = form.save(commit=False)
    prefer.save()
    return HttpResponse('Order Complete')
else:
    return HttpResponse('Some Problem')
```

When I run the app, it just display the line 'Some Problem' without showing the form. All help/suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you print out form.errors and see if anything exists there?

Comment: Aren't you setting your HttpResponse to 'Some Problem'? Shouldn't you maybe be sending ('Some Problem: ' + request.form)

Comment: @Adrianopolis On doing that form is displayed but It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're only returning an `HttpResponse`. If you want to return the form to show errors you need to use `render`:

```
def pref2(request):
  form = PreferenceForm(request.POST or None)

  if form.is_valid():
    prefer = form.save(commit=False)
    prefer.save()

  # Good practice here would be to flash a message on success
  # and on failure.

  return render(request, "template.html", { "form": form })
```

Comment: I changed the view to -

    if form.is_valid():
        prefer = form.save(commit=False)
        prefer.save()
        return render(request, 'website/detail.html', {'prefer': prefer})
    else:
        return render(request, 'website/pref2.html', {'form': form})

It displays the form but it is not working.